# join two tables on id from json column in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Trying to accomplish this;

TABLE PRODUCTS

```
id | product_id | product
------------------------------
 1 |         123|  acme widget
------------------------------
 2 |         456|  acme gadget
```

TABLE ORDERS

```
id | lineItems
------------------------------
 1 | [{ id: 123, quantity: 10}, { id: 456, quantity: 5}]
```

USING

```
SELECT a.*
FROM orders a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN products b ON b.product_id = a.products -> 'id'
```

in order to return

```
id | product_id | product     | quantity
------------------------------------------
 1 |        123 | acme widget |       10
------------------------------------------
 1 |        456 | acme gadget |        5
```

Comment: You want display like "in order to return "

Answer (score -1):

I solved this. I created a view

```
CREATE VIEW view_lineItems
AS 
SELECT
    aa.id AS order_id, 
    -- (p->>'id')::bigint AS product_id,
    bb.*,
    (p->>'quantity')::integer AS quantity
    FROM public.pim_orders aa, json_array_elements(aa.products) p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pim_batch bb ON bb.product_id = (p->>'id')::bigint
    ORDER BY aa.id;
```

and then joined that view to the original query (stored procedure) and called in the columns I needed.

because of the nature of the line items view i wasn't able to create a primary key - which I would need for a materialized view - as it is possible for there to be multiple products as each line item, and also possible for the same product to be listed multiple times for different orders.

but this worked fine for my needs :) I'm now able to decide which view I'll join specific tables for returned results - whether on the order, or on the line item.

cheers!